# Heroku + Grails - missing DATABASE_URL when building app on heroku

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to connect my application to Shared Database 5MB using grails tutorial. I'm using grails 2.1.0. On my local machine when I run heroku config I can see that DATABASE_URL is set, but after executing git push... my build stops with error:

```
Error packaging application: Error loading DataSource.groovy: null (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Failed to build app
Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Grails app
```

So I've added logging to see how environment looks on heroku. I've added println System.env to Datasource.groovy and I cannot find any DATABASE_URL:

```
.[OLDPWD:/app/tmp/repo.git/.cache, SHELL:/bin/bash, SHLVL:2, GIT_DIR:., JAVA_HOME:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk, PATH:/app/tmp/repo.git/.cache/.grails/bin::/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin, SSH_CLIENT:XXX, MAIL:XXX, USER:XXX, LOG_TOKEN:t.9e79a5be-dfa2-446e-9f83-f6b4ebbc4eb7, GRAILS_HOME:/app/tmp/repo.git/.cache/.grails, PWD:XXX, HOME:/app/, LOGNAME:u11846, _:/app/tmp/repo.git/.cache/.grails/bin/grails, SSH_CONNECTION:XXX, LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/../lib/amd64]
```

I have checked with heroku addons that for my application shared database is installed:

```
heroku addons
=== XXX Configured Add-ons
shared-database:5mb
```

and when I execute heroku config

```
heroku config
=== Config Vars for XXX

DATABASE_URL:        postgres://XXX
JAVA_OPTS:           -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops
SHARED_DATABASE_URL: postgres://XXX
```

Datasource.groovy:

```
production {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
        dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

        println System.env
        println System.env.DATABASE_URL
        uri = new URI(System.env.DATABASE_URL)
        println uri

        url = "jdbc:postgresql://" + uri.host + uri.path
        username = uri.userInfo.split(":")[0]
        password = uri.userInfo.split(":")[1]
    }
}
```

In BuildConfig.groovy I've added

```
runtime 'postgresql:postgresql:8.4-702.jdbc3'
```

I can launch application locally with DATABASE_URL set to local postgresql. I'm building war and running it on jetty.

Can anyone tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application environment variables are not available at build time.  Your code needs to be able to handle that accordingly.  Or you can enable the new `user_env_compile` Heroku Labs feature that does enable the environment variables to be there at build time:   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile