# trying to test connection to database

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I am using [Heroku](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps) and have a new application created and a Postgres empty database setup.

I've got the Heroku toolbelt installed and can login to Heroku and successfully run the following commands:

```
c:\>heroku pg:info mydbname --app my-app-name
```

and

```
c:\>heroku pg:credentials mydbname --app my-app-name
```

Now, that I have my app and an empty db created, I'm trying to make a successful connection to the database.

I'm using Ruby.  I have a local copy of my project and I'm trying to create a simple ruby file to make a connection to the database.  I'm just trying to prove that I can connect to the database from my application.

I was looking at the activerecord option [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack#database-access)

But, I'm not having much luck.

Can any heroku/postgres guru help point me in the right direction.  The database is empty.  All I'm trying to do is make a successful connection to the database as a first step.

Ruby file:

```
require 'active_record'
require 'uri'

db = URI.parse(ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || 'postgres://localhost/jade')

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => db.scheme == 'postgres' ? 'postgresql' : db.scheme,
  :host     => db.host,
  :port     => db.port,
  :username => db.user,
  :password => db.password,
  :database => db.path[1..-1],
  :encoding => 'utf8'
)
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm completely new to heroku, ruby and postgres, so please excuse any novice questions or answers on my part.  I tried creating a ruby file with the script shown for database access using activerecord, but when I run it I get an error saying I need to install the postgresql adapter, but I have installed that gem.  I ran `gem list` and  the postgresql adapter gem is listed.  I'm not sure where to look or how to debug the problem?

Comment: "I tried creating a ruby file with the script shown for database access" That's exactly what we want to see. That ruby file.

Comment: I've edited my original post to include the ruby file.

Answer (score 1):

What is the content of ENV['DATABASE_URL']
Can you try it with
**enable user-env-compile**

Making an app’s config vars present during the build allows for build-time optimizations to run in an environment that more closely resembles the runtime environment. This also allows config vars to be used to configure the build.

```
$ heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a myapp
-----> Enabling user-env-compile for myapp... done
WARNING: This feature is experimental and may change or be removed without notice.
```

May help you [missing-database-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502305/heroku-grails-missing-database-url-when-building-app-on-heroku)

**EDIT:**

confirm that your database YAML file is being parsed properly.

```
ruby -ryaml -e "File.open('config/database.yml') { |f| puts YAML.load(f).inspect }"
```

**Configuring a PostgreSQL Database**

your config/database.yml customized to use PostgreSQL databases:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: MyDb
  pool: 5
  username: meuser
  password:
```

**Another Tip**
Look if you have a file called `Gemfile` in the root directory of your Rails app.
Look for `gem 'pg'` otherwise add it.

Comment: I output the db variable and it shows: `postgres://localhost/jade` I don't have postgres running locally so that should not be the path.  I thought the `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` would return the appropriate db url from the remote db instance? I also enabled `enable  user-env-compile` and got the same error for me to install postgresql adapter.  Am I correct that the database url should be pointing to the remote db instance in heroku?

Comment: Have you tested setting the `:host     => 'localhost',
  :username => 'meuser',
  :password => 'mypassword', ... ` **manually** ?

Comment: I ran the credentials command: `heroku pg:credentials mydbname --app myappname`.  I then manually entered those credentials into the ruby script file.  Everytime, I run the file, I get "Please intall postgresql adapter". Running `gem list` shows I have the postgresql adapter installed.

Comment: It looks like the name of your postgresql database adapter is "postgres" rename it to "postgresql", fix the database.yml.

Comment: My apologies...I'm not clear on where I change "postgres" to "postgresql".  I looked in the databasedotcom.yml file and it just includes the name/value pair for client_id, client_secret, host, username, and password.  I don't see postgres in that file? Is that were I should add it? Or, is there somewhere else it needs to change?

Comment: I ran the command: `ruby -ryaml -e "File.open('databasedotcom.yml') { |if| puts YAML.load(f).inspect }"` and it returned the name/value  pairs for: client_id, client_secret, host, username, and password.  The client_id is a long encrypted string, client_secret is a number. There is no database.yml file or a config directory.  Only the databasedotcom.yml file.

Comment: yes, the gemfile does have `gem "pg"` as well as `gem "harvested"`, `gem "databasedotcom"`, and `gem "salesforce)_bulk_api"`.  Nothing else in the gemfile at the moment.

Comment: have you created "config/database.yml" with content shown above?

Comment: Yes, I did manually create the config folder and the database.yml file.  I ran the connection.rb file and still got the error: `Please install the postgresql adapter`.  I'm wondering if the bundler can even find the installed gems?  Could that be the issue?

Comment: you had no config folder in your project? is it possible to create a new project. [Getting Started](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=_jWUOn8z-UM#!)